# 文字列をjsonで辞書に変換し、辞書内の値をprintする方法

Tags: python, json

以下のようなコードを試してみたのですがうまくいきません。

```
import json
test = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3]'
mylist = json.loads(test)
print(mylist["a"])
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

どうしたら文字列を辞書に変換した後、"a"の値である1を取り出せますか？

Comment: まぁ、書き間違いかと思いますが、`test = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3]'` は `test = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'` です(right bracket `]` ではなく right brace`}`)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

閉じカッコが`]`になってしまっています。`}`に修正してください。

エラーメッセージは1行目の19文字目付近に問題があると言っているので、このようなエラーに出くわした時は、まずそこを確認してみてください。